# State of canvas support in CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, canvas

What's the state of canvas support in CSS (in 2011)? I came across couple of blog post from webkit and mozilla regarding this:

http://www.webkit.org/blog/176/css-canvas-drawing/

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/mozelement/

and also somewhat related stackoverflow question:

[Use <canvas> as a CSS background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background)

It would be great to create less sophisticated icons/graphics via scripting instead of using Graphics editors and managing sprites.

Is there any momentum in the IE camp towards this implementation?

Waiting for the day when this technique becomes mainstream!

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20canvas