# processing.js using sketches as backgrounds

Tags: css, background, processing, processing.js

I want to use a sketch written with PDE as a background to a webpage.  Is this possible?

I tried using the sketch.pde file in this css code but no joy:

```
html {
background: url(sketch.pde) no-repeat center center fixed;

}
```

*Update*

I set the canvas up like this:

```
<canvas id="twit" data-processing-sources="twit.pde"
height="window.innerHeight-10"     
width="window.innerWidth" 
tabindex="0" 
style="image-rendering">
</canvas>
```

And then refer to the canvas in the .css using the -moz-element:

```
{background: -moz-element(#twit) no-repeat;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, .pde is a text file not an image file. Therefore it won't work as a background. The only ways I've seen pde displayed are with the `canvas` HTML element and a java applet but I have no experience doing it myself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background) other SO question might be able to help out with making the `canvas` appear to be a background along with checking out the source of the processing-js [main page](http://processingjs.org/) to find out how they put it into the element.

Comment: Thanks Sparrow.  You got me on the right track.  I've now cracked it!  Code in the original question