# Make <canvas> the background of an html document

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

Is there a way I can make an HTML5 canvas the background of a web page I am making and place all the elements on top of it.

So it acts like the `<body>`?

I tried doing this with z-index and positioning the elements on top, but then they were click-able or focus-able. I need them to still be functioning, but the canvas to also be clickable just in the background and not clickable where there are elements over it.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background/43105694#43105694

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the `<canvas>`'s `z-index` to `-1`. If your canvas is covered by containers on top, simulate custom events using [`createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent).<sup>[[1]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)</sup>

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uw5XU/

```
var canvas = $("canvas"),  //jQuery selector, similar to querySelectorAll()
//...

function simulate(e) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("mousemove", true, true, window,
        0, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    canvas[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
}

$("body > *").each(function () {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", simulate);
});
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I think what I was missing was the custom events. Can you show me an example of how to use custom events to simulate clicking on a canvas when there is actually a container on top?

Comment: If the top layer should be invisible to mouse interactions, set `pointer-events: none`.

Comment: @alex - This is no top layer in my demo... (since I just updated it you might have to reload the page) Nevertheless, this is still a great comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sure that would be possible with `z-index`, most probably the canvas will not be clickable because you're working with a container that's on top of it. So even if there appears to be no element the container is still there which prevents you from clicking on the canvas.