# Setting Canvas to Background - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, background

I am trying to figure out how to turn the canvas I have created into the background image of the HTML body. Thanks!

```
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript">
    function draw() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
      canvas.style.background = '#D1E0FF';
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
        context.fillStyle = '#FF8533';
        context.fillRect (
            Math.round(Math.random()*300*100)/100,
            Math.round(Math.random()*300*100)/100,
            30,
            30
          );
      }
    var backgroundURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    ???
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="300px" height="300px"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9369248/1267304) answer, you can try this:

```
$('body').css({'background-image':"url(" + canvas.toDataURL("image/png")+ ")" });
```

Comment: 'image/png' would be needed, none the less a good answer.

Comment: @Wayne yeah, or whatever is the image's mime-type.

Answer (score 2):

With CSS you can use

`-webkit-canvas` of course only on webkit browsers. To achieve a similar effect on Firefox you would use

`-moz-element`

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/R9abU/)**

### CSS

```
body{
    background: -webkit-canvas(background);
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d', 'background', 300, 300);

// make some random rects
var i = 50;
while(i--){
    ctx.fillRect(Math.random()*300, Math.random()*300, Math.random()*50, Math.random()*50);
}
```

[More Information on webkit method](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/12/Canvas-driven-background-images)

[More information on Firefox method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.mozSetImageElement)

Answer (score 1):

if you were using jQuery

```
$('body').css("background-image", backgroundURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

toDataURL method returns a URL equivalent., you need to place it in a place for a URL.

```
object.style.backgroundImage="url("+canvas.toDataURL()+")";
```

I would tag the body element with an ID for this.

```
document.getElementById("mypage").style.backgroundImage="url("+canvas.toDataURL()+")";
```

There are of course other ways to get the body object.

**Update**

per dontvotemedown, I believe you need argument for toDataURL()