# How are new lines made with text as background?

Tags: html, css, text, ascii-art

Referencing this question:
[Is there a way to use use text as the background with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191464/is-there-a-way-to-use-use-text-as-the-background-with-css)

I was able to make one line of text appear behind another line of text. 
What I am having trouble figuring out is how to make multiple lines of background text. 
Here's the pattern i want to use:
http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/scope/bgScope

So inserting it directly didn't work, everything was on one line.
 OK, I thought, I'll use a `<pre></pre>` set of tags, but that made the background text invisible.
So then I tried taking out the `pre` tags, and putting in `<br>` on each new line. But it still nothing. Next I tried putting

```
font-family: Courier;
font-size: 18px;
color:#167c11;
```

into the style sheet, but, the text in the background is still invisible.

Have a look at the page where i am trying to get newlines into the text as a background.
http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/scope/

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? How can I get multiple lines of text as a background in CSS?

Comment: You might consider [using a canvas to draw the grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642485/setting-canvas-to-background-javascript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use absolute positioning and z-index to add the background effect.

```
body{
    background:black;
    color:green;

}
#background{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor:default;
}
#content{
    color:red;
    font-family: Courier;
}
```

The rules:

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */        
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
        /* Rules below not implemented in browsers yet */
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        cursor:default;
```

give it a background effect making it so the text cannot be selected and the cursor is default instead of text.
The html is very simple:

```
<div id="background">
<pre>

    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
    +---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
_____________________________________________________________________________________________________
t1:288 ms  t2:480 ms    Display Mode: Normal: Peak Detect    Vectors: OFF       Grid = FULL


</pre>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            I am content and I am above the grid!
        </div>
```

[Check out this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/cr4zM/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/adriantombu/LNCXB/

I made some changes to your html and css, you can see what it does on the jsfiddel above.

```
body {
    background-color:#000000;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 18px;
    color:#167c11;    
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    color:#FF0011;
}

#background {

    color:#167c11;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
#background pre {
    margin: 0; padding: 0
}

#content {

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```