# Is there a way to use any element as a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Examples I see using `<canvas>` always have an actual canvas element in the HTML. Say I for example already have a `<header>` element that I would like to draw on, is there a way to use it as a canvas directly? Or do I need to add that canvas element and make sure it's filling the header?

Comment: Nope. Other html elements do not have the html5 canvas' capabilities. Just add an actual canvas element as a child of your header.

Answer (score 1):

I was skeptical at first, but there is one way to achieve *almost* that, by using css and `getCSSCanvasContext()` with the webkit. This allows you to display a canvas as a background so you can control it like a canvas.

Ex:

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
```

**CSS**

```
header { background: -webkit-canvas(fooBar); }
```

**JavaScript** (when document ready / onload)

```
function fillCanvas(w, h) {
   var ctx = document.getCSSCanvasContext('2d', 'fooBar', w, h);

   // draw into canvas
}
```

A complete example and more specs are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397334/use-canvas-as-a-css-background).

Hope this is convenient.

Comment: Upvote for an interesting alternative, but you might as well CSS position an actual canvas element under or put a canvas element inside the header.

Comment: From chrome 46 this was removed. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=475655 though `-moz-element` may still be around dont rely on it. You can set the background to a rendered canvas via `canvas.toDataURL` and  css `URL("url");`  though it is slow.