# Can't import css houdini paint js file

Tags: css, reactjs, electron, css-houdini, css-paint-api

I have a React/Electron app, where I'm trying to use the new CSS Houdini `paint()` function (as demonstrated [in this page](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-create-randomly-generated-backgrounds-with-the-css-paint-api/)). In my project's `index.html` file I have added a script tag with the paintWorklet `addModule()` function as shown:

```
<script>
  CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('../src/ResultDisplay/DefaultResultDisplay/testPaint.js');
</script>
```

Then in that `testPaint.js` file I have essentially a copy of what's shown in that blog post:

```
registerPaint(
  "testPaint",
  class {
    paint(ctx, geom) {
      console.log("painting!!!");
      const circleSize = 10;
      const bodyWidth = geom.width;
      const bodyHeight = geom.height;

      const maxX = Math.floor(bodyWidth / circleSize);
      const maxY = Math.floor(bodyHeight / circleSize);

      for (let y = 0; y < maxY; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < maxX; x++) {
          ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(
            x * circleSize * 2 + circleSize,
            y * circleSize * 2 + circleSize,
            circleSize,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI,
            true
          );
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.fill();
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

And finally my css file:

```
.container {
  background-image: paint(testPaint);
  display: flex;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

I should point out I am using CSS Modules, so this file is `defaultResultStyles.module.scss`; not sure if that affects anything. When I bring up the component that's meant to have these styles in my app, it has no styles, though inspecting it, it does display `background-image: paint(testPaint). The console.log that I added to the` testPaint.js` file is never shown.

I have tried multiple variations of the filepath for `addModule`; I've tried just `testPaint.js`, starting it with `./src` and `src` both, but nothing seems to work; is this possible in an Electron/React app?

Comment: You can throw the file in your src dir along with everything else and then resolve it to a URL instead of compiling it like normal like this `import angledCorners from '!file-loader!./css-paint/angled-corners';` -- that's a feature of wepack. Then you can add it `CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(angledCorners);` but that's as far as I got... I can see the file loading but it's not painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addModule function will not work through webpack or other bundlers, it instead works through the native module system of browsers. You have to put the `testPaint.js` file in the public directory, otherwise it would get bundled with everything else.

Here's what I added to the index.html to get it to run from the public directory on a local Create React App project:

```
    <script>
      CSS.paintWorklet.addModule('%PUBLIC_URL%/testPaint.js');
    </script>
```

I didn't actuallly set up any of the markup and just added the container class to test it out:
[image]

---

If you want to use this without going through the public folder (at all, because normally you'd have to add the paint module in the index.html which is changing the public directory), then I'd suggest using [React Helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) to set up the script tags. As a note with this, the hot-reload features of CRA seems to prevent the scripts from updating, so every time you change the script tags, you'll need to refresh the page manually.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Render these styled components like normal react components.
// They will pass on all props and work
// like normal react components – except they're styled!
const Demo = styled.div`
  background: #1108a0;
  padding: 50px 0;
`;
const Test = styled.div`
  --color: cyan;
  --multiplier: 0.24;
  --pad: 30;
  --slant: 20;
  background: paint(background-canvas);
  transition: --multiplier 0.4s;
  font: bold 6em sans-serif;
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 1px cyan;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  width: max-content;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  isolation: isolate;
  &:hover {
    --multiplier: 1;
  }
  & span {
    mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
  }
`;
export const App = () => (
  <Demo>
    <Test className="el" right={'right'}>
      <span>JS-in-CSS</span>
    </Test>
  </Demo>
);
export const Helm = () => (
  <Helmet>
    <script language="javascript+paint">{`
  registerPaint('background-canvas', class {
  static get inputProperties() {
      return ['--multiplier', '--color', '--pad', '--slant'];
  }
  paint(ctx, geom, properties) {
    let multiplier = +properties.get('--multiplier').toString();
    let c = properties.get('--color').toString();
    let pad = +properties.get('--pad').toString();
    let slant = +properties.get('--slant').toString();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(pad + (geom.width - slant - pad) * multiplier, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(pad + (geom.width - slant - pad) * multiplier + slant, geom.height);
    ctx.lineTo(0, geom.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = c;
    ctx.fill();
  }
})
`}</script>

    <script>{`
  if ("paintWorklet" in CSS) {
  const src = document.querySelector('script[language$="paint"]').innerHTML;
  const blob = new Blob([src], {
    type: 'text/javascript'
  });
  CSS.paintWorklet.addModule(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
}
`}</script>
  </Helmet>
);
render(
  <div>
    <Helm />
    <App />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: That makes sense I guess. Is there any way around this? It's not ideal to be putting that code in the `public` directory...

Comment: @IronWaffleMan, I've added a way to avoid the public directory. I'm not really sure what the issue with using the public directory is. That's what it's there for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to avoid using /public, you can use a monorepo manager like Yarn Workspaces to keep your worklet in a dedicated package. Then, you can import it into your client app like you would any other package dependency.

Step by step (using Yarn Workspaces):

1. create dedicated packages for your app (package.json name is @packages/myapp) and worklet (@packages/myworklet)
2. add your worklet as a dependency to your app -- from @packages/myapp run yarn add @packages/myworklet
3. import your worklet from @packages/myworklet and add it -- see https://houdini.how/usage/